# How can I create a custom column type with Typesafe Slick in Scala?

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I have a PostgreSQL table with an `enum`, which is created by:

```
CREATE TYPE file_status AS ENUM ('new', 'uploading', 'queued', 'processing', 'done', 'failed');
```

and an associated field

```
CREATE TABLE files ( ...
    status file_status NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

With Scala 2.10 and Typesafe Slick 1.0.1, I've created mappings to my Files table that work great with the exception of the `status` field, which requires the custom `file_status` type, a string.

```
def status = column[FileStatus]("status")
```

I've been playing with Slick's TypeMapper, but can't quite figure out how to get it to work:

```
sealed trait FileStatus

implicit val fileStatusMapper: TypeMapper[String] = base[FileStatus, String](
  s => s.toString,
  f => f(FileStatus)
)
```

I get the error: *type mismatch; found : models.Files.FileStatus.type required: Int*

Why is an Int required? Is it because of the TypeMapper? I have also tried

```
...
f => f.toString
// type mismatch; found : String required: models.Files.FileStatus

f => f
// type mismatch; found : String required: models.Files.FileStatus
```

Thank you for any pointers in helping me understand this mapping.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting from the docs (http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/lifted-embedding.html#user-defined-functions-and-types):

```
// An algebraic data type for booleans
sealed trait Bool
case object True extends Bool
case object False extends Bool

// And a TypeMapper that maps it to Int values 1 and 0
implicit val boolTypeMapper = MappedTypeMapper.base[Bool, Int](
  { b => if(b == True) 1 else 0 },    // map Bool to Int
  { i => if(i == 1) True else False } // map Int to Bool
)
```

Adapting this to file status:

```
sealed trait FileStatus
case object New extends FileStatus
case object Uploading extends FileStatus
...

implicit val fileStatusTypeMapper = MappedTypeMapper.base[FileStatus, String](
  {
    case New => "new"
    case Uploading => "uploading"
    ...
  },{
    case "new" => New
    case "uploading" => Uploading
    ...
  }
)
```

**Update:**

Another, less redundant, but possibly also less clear version:

```
sealed trait FileStatus
case object New extends FileStatus
case object Uploading extends FileStatus
...

val statusMap = Map(
    New -> "new",
    Uploading -> "uploading",
    ...
)

implicit val fileStatusTypeMapper = MappedTypeMapper.base[FileStatus, String](
  statusMap,
  statusMap.map(_.swap)
)
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you--creating case objects was the piece I was skipping, for whatever reason. Thanks @cvogt

Comment: Update: added an alternative implementation :)

Comment: `MappedTypeMapper` has been renamed to `MappedColumnType`.
http://scala-slick.org/doc/3.0.0/upgrade.html#mapped-column-types

Answer (score 4):

Slick 3.x version:

```
    sealed trait FileStatus
    case object New extends FileStatus
    case object Uploading extends FileStatus
    ...

   implicit val fileStatusColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[FileStatus, String](
   {
     case New => "new"
     case Uploading => "uploading"
     ...
    },{
     case "new" => New
     case "uploading" => Uploading
     ...
   }
 )
```